# Deleting Multiple Rows with BatchUpdate in Python / Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

I'm taking a spreadsheet of employee data and separating it by each division in the company. Prior to separating, I want to delete data that doesn't belong to the appropriate division (currentDiv) by comparing to the Division value (rowF[8]) in each row. I'm using batchUpdate for this, but am open to other methods.

```
rowsDeleted = 0
for i, rowF in enumerate(filterValues):                       
    currentDiv = rowF[8]
    deleteRequest = []
    if division[1] != currentDiv:
       deleteRequest.append({
       'deleteDimension': {
       'sheetId': dupeId,
       'dimension': "ROWS",
       'startIndex': i - rowsDeleted,
       'endIndex': i - rowsDeleted
       }
       })
       rowsDeleted = rowsDeleted + 1
       try:
       deleteRequest = {"requests:": deleteRequest}
       request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId = meritMain, body = deleteRequest)
       response = request.execute()
       print(response)
       except HttpError as err:
           print(err)
```

The error I'm receiving is `invalid JSON payload, unknown name "requests", cannot find field.` I know that the issue is in how I'm appending each row to the batch request.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be removing the semicolon, ie updating:

```
deleteRequest = {"requests:": deleteRequest}
```

to

```
deleteRequest = {"requests": deleteRequest}
```